# Serenity BDD (Selenium, JUnit, Maven, IEDriver64): Checking a checkbox doesn't enable the underlying options

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, serenity-bdd

This is not really a Serenity question but close to Selenium.

When the test run it checks the checkbox, visible on the page and the functionality expects underlying options to be visible once the checkbox is checked.

However, the test run does check the checkbox, however, the underlying options remain invisible.

When I put a breakpoint on it and do it manually, it does work perfectly, as expected.

Also, interestingly, if the automation script checks the checkbox and I again uncheck the checkbox using the script debugger, the underlying option becomes visible with checkbox unchecked - weird, isn't it?

What could be the possible reason?

Any help would be appreciated.

Code Block:

```
Case.chkbxNewPolicy.click(); //Here it selects the checkbox                      
Case.selectEntityType.selectByVisibleText(param.get("CaseType").toString()); //Here it is expected to enable the underlying objects
Case.editNewPolicyNum.type(param.get("PolicyNo").toString());
Case.editAdviserId.type(param.get("AdviserId").toString());
```

//HTML

```html
</div>
<div id="createNewContainer" G360ComponentSpec="type:AdjustableContainer;fs:f;dc:f;cl:f;ic:f;" G360LayoutSpec="l:4;lip:t;lif:f;t:28;tip:t;tif:f;r:142;riw:t;rip:t;rif:f;ra:+-;b:23;bih:t;bip:t;bif:f;ba:+-;o:auto;lbpx:4;tbpx:28;wbpx:142;hbpx:23;efwpx:0;"
style="position:absolute; left:4px; top:28px; width:142px; height:23px; overflow:auto;">
  <div id="component_25" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldComponent;dt:1;format:input;fh:CheckBox;" G360LayoutSpec="l:0;lip:t;lif:f;t:2;tip:t;tif:f;r:135;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:20;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:0;tbpx:2;wbpx:135;hbpx:20;efwpx:0;"
  style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:2px; width:135px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;"><span class="fielderror" id="IS_NEWPOLICYerror"></span>
    <input name="IS_NEWPOLICY" id="IS_NEWPOLICY" type="checkbox" value="true" onclick="displayPolicyEntry(this)" onchange="setDirtyFlag(true,this);">Create New Policy
    <input type="hidden" name="IS_NEWPOLICYoriginal" id="IS_NEWPOLICYoriginal" value="false" />
    <input type="hidden" name="IS_NEWPOLICYsemaphore" id="IS_NEWPOLICYsemaphore" value="write" />
    <input type="hidden" name="IS_NEWPOLICYformatter" id="IS_NEWPOLICYformatter" value="Check Box:label=Create New Policy" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="SELECT_POLICY_DETAILS" G360ComponentSpec="type:AdjustableContainer;fs:f;dc:f;cl:f;ic:f;" G360LayoutSpec="l:9;lip:t;lif:f;t:50;tip:t;tif:f;r:762;riw:t;rip:t;rif:f;ra:+-;b:62;bih:t;bip:t;bif:f;ba:+-;o:auto;lbpx:9;tbpx:50;wbpx:762;hbpx:62;efwpx:0;"
style="position:absolute; left:9px; top:50px; width:762px; height:62px; overflow:auto;">
  <div id="component_18" G360ComponentSpec="type:HtmlTextComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:25;lip:t;lif:f;t:5;tip:t;tif:f;r:94;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:25;tbpx:5;wbpx:94;hbpx:16;efwpx:0;" style="background-color:#E6E6E6; position:absolute; left:25px; top:5px; width:94px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="">Policy Number</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_19" G360ComponentSpec="type:HtmlTextComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:260;lip:t;lif:f;t:5;tip:t;tif:f;r:75;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:260;tbpx:5;wbpx:75;hbpx:16;efwpx:0;" style="background-color:#E6E6E6; position:absolute; left:260px; top:5px; width:75px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="">Adviser ID</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_20" G360ComponentSpec="type:HtmlTextComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:350;lip:t;lif:f;t:5;tip:t;tif:f;r:90;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:350;tbpx:5;wbpx:90;hbpx:16;efwpx:0;" style="background-color:#E6E6E6; position:absolute; left:350px; top:5px; width:90px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="">Adviser Name</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_107" G360ComponentSpec="type:HtmlTextComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:474;lip:t;lif:f;t:5;tip:t;tif:f;r:70;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:474;tbpx:5;wbpx:70;hbpx:16;efwpx:0;" style="background-color:#E6E6E6; position:absolute; left:474px; top:5px; width:70px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="">Partner ID</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_41" G360ComponentSpec="type:HtmlTextComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:565;lip:t;lif:f;t:5;tip:t;tif:f;r:80;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:565;tbpx:5;wbpx:80;hbpx:16;efwpx:0;" style="background-color:#E6E6E6; position:absolute; left:565px; top:5px; width:80px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="">MP Number</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_42" G360ComponentSpec="type:HtmlTextComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:654;lip:t;lif:f;t:5;tip:t;tif:f;r:102;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:654;tbpx:5;wbpx:102;hbpx:16;efwpx:1;" style="background-color:#E6E6E6; position:absolute; left:654px; top:5px; width:102px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="">Fund Member ID</label>
  </div>
  <div id="container_18" G360ComponentSpec="type:XmlNodeContainer;fs:f;dc:f;cl:f;ic:f;" G360LayoutSpec="l:4;lip:t;lif:f;t:22;tip:t;tif:f;r:753;riw:t;rip:t;rif:f;ra:+-;b:33;bih:t;bip:t;bif:f;ba:+-;o:auto;lbpx:4;tbpx:22;wbpx:753;hbpx:33;efwpx:0;" style="position:absolute; left:4px; top:22px; width:753px; height:33px; overflow:auto;">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="NEW_POLICY_DETAILS" G360ComponentSpec="type:AdjustableContainer;fs:f;dc:f;cl:f;ic:f;" G360LayoutSpec="l:4;lip:t;lif:f;t:53;tip:t;tif:f;r:732;riw:t;rip:t;rif:f;ra:+-;b:59;bih:t;bip:t;bif:f;ba:+-;o:auto;lbpx:4;tbpx:53;wbpx:732;hbpx:59;efwpx:35;"
style="position:absolute; left:4px; top:53px; width:732px; height:59px; overflow:auto;">
  <div id="component_51" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldNameComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:2;lip:t;lif:t;t:9;tip:t;tif:t;r:72;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:2;tbpx:9;wbpx:72;hbpx:16;efwpx:46;" style="padding:1px; position:absolute; left:2px; top:9px; width:72px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="ENTITY_TYPE" style="margin-left:1px;margin-right:1px;">Entity Type</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_23" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldNameComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:122;lip:t;lif:t;t:9;tip:t;tif:t;r:93;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:122;tbpx:9;wbpx:93;hbpx:16;efwpx:109;" style="padding:1px; position:absolute; left:122px; top:9px; width:93px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="POLICY_NUM" style="margin-left:1px;margin-right:1px;">Policy Number</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_21" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldNameComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:327;lip:t;lif:t;t:9;tip:t;tif:t;r:68;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:327;tbpx:9;wbpx:68;hbpx:16;efwpx:24;" style="padding:1px; position:absolute; left:327px; top:9px; width:68px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="ADVISER_ID" style="margin-left:1px;margin-right:1px;">Adviser ID</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_101" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldNameComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:424;lip:t;lif:f;t:9;tip:t;tif:f;r:68;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:17;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:424;tbpx:9;wbpx:68;hbpx:17;efwpx:116;" style="padding:1px; position:absolute; left:424px; top:9px; width:68px; height:17px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="PARTNER_ID" style="margin-left:1px;margin-right:1px;">Partner ID</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_53" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldNameComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:426;lip:t;lif:t;t:9;tip:t;tif:t;r:173;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:426;tbpx:9;wbpx:173;hbpx:16;efwpx:9;" style="padding:1px; position:absolute; left:426px; top:9px; width:173px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="FUND_ID" style="margin-left:1px;margin-right:1px;">MP Number</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_55" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldNameComponent;" G360LayoutSpec="l:618;lip:t;lif:t;t:9;tip:t;tif:t;r:102;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:16;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:618;tbpx:9;wbpx:102;hbpx:16;efwpx:11;" style="padding:1px; position:absolute; left:618px; top:9px; width:102px; height:16px; overflow:hidden;">
    <label for="FUND_MEMBER_ID" style="margin-left:1px;margin-right:1px;">Fund Member ID</label>
  </div>
  <div id="component_102" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldComponent;dt:4;format:input;fh:none;" G360LayoutSpec="l:426;lip:t;lif:f;t:29;tip:t;tif:f;r:94;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:22;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:426;tbpx:29;wbpx:94;hbpx:22;efwpx:88;"
  style="position:absolute; left:426px; top:29px; width:94px; height:22px; overflow:hidden;">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="*" />
        <col width="18px" />
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" name="PARTNER_ID" id="PARTNER_ID" style="width:70px;height:15px;" onchange="TextValidate(this,null,128,null);" />
          <input type="hidden" name="PARTNER_IDsemaphore" id="PARTNER_IDsemaphore" value="write" />
          <input type="hidden" name="PARTNER_IDformatter" id="PARTNER_IDformatter" value="none" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="anchorNoLink" style="width:18px;position:relative;top:1px;">
            <a id="PARTNER_IDerrora" href="javascript:alert('');" style="display:none;">
              <img id="PARTNER_IDerrorimg" src="Images/fielderror.gif" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="component_52" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldComponent;dt:4;format:input;fh:none;" G360LayoutSpec="l:3;lip:t;lif:t;t:30;tip:t;tif:t;r:117;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:22;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:3;tbpx:30;wbpx:117;hbpx:22;efwpx:0;" style="position:absolute; left:3px; top:30px; width:117px; height:22px; overflow:hidden;">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="*" />
        <col width="18px" />
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="ENTITY_TYPE" id="ENTITY_TYPE" style="width:99px;" tabindex="1" onchange="setDirtyFlag(true,this);policyTypeSelected();">
            <option selected value="NA">--Please Select --</option>
            <option value="C">Retail Life Insured</option>
            <option value="M">Group Life Insured</option>
            <option value="A">Adviser</option>
            <option value="F">Fund</option>
            <option value="P">Partner</option>
            <option value="S">Special Member</option>
            <option value="U">Function</option>
          </select>
          <input type="hidden" name="ENTITY_TYPEoriginal" id="ENTITY_TYPEoriginal" value="TkE*" />
          <input type="hidden" name="ENTITY_TYPEsemaphore" id="ENTITY_TYPEsemaphore" value="write" />
          <input type="hidden" name="ENTITY_TYPEformatter" id="ENTITY_TYPEformatter" value="none" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="anchorNoLink" style="width:18px;position:relative;top:1px;">
            <a id="ENTITY_TYPEerrora" href="javascript:alert('');" style="display:none;">
              <img id="ENTITY_TYPEerrorimg" src="Images/fielderror.gif" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="component_24" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldComponent;dt:4;format:input;fh:none;" G360LayoutSpec="l:124;lip:t;lif:t;t:30;tip:t;tif:t;r:200;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:22;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:124;tbpx:30;wbpx:200;hbpx:22;efwpx:0;"
  style="position:absolute; left:124px; top:30px; width:200px; height:22px; overflow:hidden;">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="*" />
        <col width="18px" />
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" name="POLICY_NUM" id="POLICY_NUM" style="width:176px;height:15px;" tabindex="2" maxlength="30" onchange="TextValidate(this,null,30,null);" />
          <input type="hidden" name="POLICY_NUMsemaphore" id="POLICY_NUMsemaphore" value="write" />
          <input type="hidden" name="POLICY_NUMformatter" id="POLICY_NUMformatter" value="none" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="anchorNoLink" style="width:18px;position:relative;top:1px;">
            <a id="POLICY_NUMerrora" href="javascript:alert('');" style="display:none;">
              <img id="POLICY_NUMerrorimg" src="Images/fielderror.gif" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="component_22" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldComponent;dt:4;format:input;fh:none;" G360LayoutSpec="l:329;lip:t;lif:t;t:30;tip:t;tif:t;r:90;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:22;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:329;tbpx:30;wbpx:90;hbpx:22;efwpx:0;"
  style="position:absolute; left:329px; top:30px; width:90px; height:22px; overflow:hidden;">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="*" />
        <col width="18px" />
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" name="ADVISER_ID" id="ADVISER_ID" style="width:66px;height:15px;" tabindex="3" maxlength="9" onchange="TextValidate(this,null,9,null);" />
          <input type="hidden" name="ADVISER_IDsemaphore" id="ADVISER_IDsemaphore" value="write" />
          <input type="hidden" name="ADVISER_IDformatter" id="ADVISER_IDformatter" value="none" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="anchorNoLink" style="width:18px;position:relative;top:1px;">
            <a id="ADVISER_IDerrora" href="javascript:alert('');" style="display:none;">
              <img id="ADVISER_IDerrorimg" src="Images/fielderror.gif" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="component_54" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldComponent;dt:4;format:input;fh:none;" G360LayoutSpec="l:428;lip:t;lif:t;t:30;tip:t;tif:t;r:180;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:22;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:428;tbpx:30;wbpx:180;hbpx:22;efwpx:0;"
  style="position:absolute; left:428px; top:30px; width:180px; height:22px; overflow:hidden;">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="*" />
        <col width="18px" />
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" name="FUND_ID" id="FUND_ID" style="width:156px;height:15px;" tabindex="4" maxlength="8" onchange="TextValidate(this,null,8,null);" />
          <input type="hidden" name="FUND_IDsemaphore" id="FUND_IDsemaphore" value="write" />
          <input type="hidden" name="FUND_IDformatter" id="FUND_IDformatter" value="none" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="anchorNoLink" style="width:18px;position:relative;top:1px;">
            <a id="FUND_IDerrora" href="javascript:alert('');" style="display:none;">
              <img id="FUND_IDerrorimg" src="Images/fielderror.gif" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="component_56" G360ComponentSpec="type:FieldComponent;dt:4;format:input;fh:none;" G360LayoutSpec="l:617;lip:t;lif:t;t:30;tip:t;tif:t;r:114;riw:t;rip:t;rif:t;ra:+-;b:22;bih:t;bip:t;bif:t;ba:+-;o:hidden;lbpx:617;tbpx:30;wbpx:114;hbpx:22;efwpx:0;"
  style="position:absolute; left:617px; top:30px; width:114px; height:22px; overflow:hidden;">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="*" />
        <col width="18px" />
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" name="FUND_MEMBER_ID" id="FUND_MEMBER_ID" style="width:90px;height:15px;" tabindex="5" maxlength="60" onchange="TextValidate(this,null,60,null);" />
          <input type="hidden" name="FUND_MEMBER_IDsemaphore" id="FUND_MEMBER_IDsemaphore" value="write" />
          <input type="hidden" name="FUND_MEMBER_IDformatter" id="FUND_MEMBER_IDformatter" value="none" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="anchorNoLink" style="width:18px;position:relative;top:1px;">
            <a id="FUND_MEMBER_IDerrora" href="javascript:alert('');" style="display:none;">
              <img id="FUND_MEMBER_IDerrorimg" src="Images/fielderror.gif" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and share your HTML?

Comment: Added the HTML @JDelorean

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reason, either there are javascript errors while rendering the underlying options which can be viewed on jconsole, or you are not waiting for the underlying options to appear.

Comment: even if I add a hard wait (60 seconds, i.e. way too much) or waitForCondition, the underlying option doesn't appear. I don't see any javascript errors, also, it works fine when i use breakpoint and do it manually.

Comment: all i can say at this moment is if you have any public url to re-create the issue at our end..only then will we be able to help as its difficult to know what's happening behind the scenes